# Sell ETC from my Ledger Nano S (Ledger Wallet Ethereum)?

Tags: ethereum-classic

I have som ETC on my Ledger Nano S and now I want to send them to my bank account. In Ledger Wallet Ethereum app I get the option to send them to a "Ethereum IBAN or account"

What is that ?? Do I need an ETC account with a exchange and from there I can then transfer to my bank account or do I miss something completely.

Best regards

Comment: Can you not just send to an exchange wallet and do it from there?

Comment: Which one would that be ?? I am very new to this so..... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create an account with an exchange that works well for the currency you want to exchange your ETC for (make sure they also accept ETC).

For example here's a short list of popular exchanges that trade ETC:

- [Bitfinex](https://www.bitfinex.com/trading)
- [Bittrex](https://bittrex.com/)
- [Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/)

Once you've done this, they'll give you an ETC wallet with an address to sent it to. Send your ETC to the ETC wallet on the exchange then trade your ETC for the fiat currency of your choice.